# Can you append values to a select element through the developer console in the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a simple web application so far that is written in php using the laravel framework.

My question is in the title: if I have a web form that has multiple `SELECT` elements, could somebody use javascript to append new options to that `SELECT' element and submit the form (therefore saving items that weren't suppose to options in my database?)?

Comment: Yes, easy. You must do server side verification of the sent data. Don't trust it. They could forge the entire request if they wanted to.

Comment: `document.querySelector("select").innerHTML = "<option value='oops'>Oops</option>"` - one-liner in the console.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have suggested, it is certainly possible to append options, or even change the values of what is being submitted.

To prevent this, you can use server side validation to check what is being passed in. Laravel provides validation out of the box that makes doing this a breeze.

The validation rule you want to use is [`in`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-in):

> The field under validation must be included in the given list of values.

Inside your controller function that receives the request, just add this at the top to validate the request before you pass it in to your database:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'select_input' => 'in:foo,bar',
        ], [
            'select_input.in' => 'The option selected was not valid!',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }
```

You would need to add these to the top of your controller:

```
use Validator;
use Input;
use Redirect;
```

There's plenty more validation that you can utilise, just read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation).